# Как обрезать строку?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка `var a = "13:45 PM"` хочу обрезать `PM` и оставить только `13:45`
Попробовал так  var `b=str.substring(5,7)` не работает ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```js
console.log("13:45 PM".split(' ')[0]); // Разделить по пробелу, взять первую часть
console.log("13:45 PM".match(/\d?\d:\d\d/)[0]); // совпадение по регулярному выражению
console.log("13:45 PM".substr(0, 5)); // 5 символов, начиная с 0го
console.log("13:45 PM".substring(0, 5)); // копировать по индексам [0:5)
console.log("13:45 PM".replace(/\s.*/, '')); // заменить пробел и всё, что дальше пустой строкой
console.log("13:45 PM".slice(0, -3)); // срез без последних трёх символов
```

Comment: А где `.replace(' PM', '');`? :)

Comment: Подозреваю, иногда там бывает `AM` :) Хотя, 13ч в am/pm...

Comment: 13ч. в 12-ти часовом формате о_О?

Comment: Определённо, это второй час ночи)

Comment: Час ночи это `1 AM`, у меня смартфон локализован под инглиш, так что точно знаю :)

Comment: ахаха))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Четко! спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = "13:45 PM";

var str = a.slice(0,5);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: А если `5:07 PM`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно используете [`String.prototype.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). Этот метод *копирует строку между указанными индексами*, а не вырезает ее (как вы наверное думали).

Вот как правильно использовать этот метод:

```
var a = '13:45 PM';
var b = a.substring(0, 6);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.slice(0,-3)
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = document.querySelector('time').innerHTML.slice(0,-3);
}
```

```html
<time>10:15 AM</time>
<button>slice me!</button>
<br>
<output></output>
```