# Как из текста извлечь 4-е первых слова

Tags: javascript

Как из длинной строки извлечь 4-е первых слова?

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var str=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; str.split(' ')[1];")
```

Этоn код извлекает только первое слово.

Comment: `str.slice(0, 4)` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/625824/256824

Comment: У вас какие-то вопросы однотипные. Возможно, что вы не можете правильно сформулировать, что вам необходимо?

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь написать макросы под конкретные задачи. Кстати, прописала `SET !VAR1 EVAL("var str=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; str.slice(0, 4);")` но все равно из текста вытягивает только первое слово.

Comment: `str.split(' ').slice(0, 4);`

Comment: @Igor Я уже поняла, что нужно прописать ещё "(' ')"  т.к. парсились 4 буквы, а не 4 слова. Теперь проблема следующая, с этим кодом `SET !VAR1 EVAL("var str=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; str.split(' ').slice(0, 4);")` я теперь спарсила 4-е первых слова из рандомного текста, но вместо пробелов появились запятые. Сохраняется текст как: "Первый,Второй,Третий,Четвертый"

Comment: @Машуня Отлично. Осталось объяснить, в каком виде Вы хотите получить эти первые четыре слова.

Comment: @Igor Вот кусок кода из imacros: 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:*a* EXTRACT=TXT 
WAIT SECONDS=1 
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var str=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; str.split(' ').slice(0,4);") 
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:myform ATTR=ID:code_textart CONTENT={{!var1}}

Comment: @Машуня Это все зачем? Повторяю вопрос: где должны оказаться четыре строки, соответствующие первым четырем словам?

Comment: @Igor 4-е слова нужно вставить в обычную форму на сайте.

Comment: @Igor Короче, мне нужно вставить эти 4 слова в форму только без запятых, которые появились вместо пробелов.

Comment: @Машуня Что значит "вставить в форму"? Где они в конце концов должны оказаться? Приведите пример.

Comment: @Igor Вопрос закрыт. Нашла способ как удалить эти запятые между словами, нужно было в конце кода добавить .join(' ');

Comment: @Машуня Молодец. Поздравляю. Успехов!

Comment: @Igor Взаимно. Ваш коммент плюсанула)

Comment: @Igor, вы видимо не работали с `imacros`, эти слова должны вставляться после разбора парсером, по таргету, куда укажем, в данном случае у нее это форма на странице, которую открыли через макрос. =)

Comment: @And Да, не работал :(. Не уловил, что они должны вставляться все вместе одной строкой. Почему-то подумал, что автору нужны четыре отдельных строки.